# Add a SQL Server in server list in Microsoft Connection UI dialog

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

This is how we generally instantiate    `DataConnectionDialog`

```
    DataConnectionDialog dlg = new DataConnectionDialog();
    DataSource.AddStandardDataSources(dlg);
    if (DataConnectionDialog.Show(dlg) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      //..
    }
```

I wish to add one SQL server in default configuration. So that every time `DataConnectionDialog` launches, it will show that server selected by default.

I found `DataConnectionConfiguration` class. I thought I can add my server name to configuration file and ask DataConnectionDialog to read it and show server name. But DataConnectionConfiguration doesn't facilitate adding server names.

Is there any other way to set a default server in DataConnectionDialog?

[image]

Comment: Did you check [AddSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb145994.aspx) ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am actually using Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.DataConnectionDialog class. Which doesn't have AddSources. AddSources comes with Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.DataConnectionDialog

Answer (score 3):

Use `ConnectionString` property of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.DataConnectionDialog` class. That did the trick.

```
dlg.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xx;Persist Security Info=True;";
```